# Session::put, ->with($data), losts after page refresh laravel4

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

Hello i have an route that redirects to other route with session params data=true, uid=$id

another route get it and show a Response::make / Response::view.
view is showed but if I reload page with F5, session data lost ( route doesn't get it ).

```
Route::get('/something', array('as'=>'activation',function()
{
   return Redirect::route('firstpass')
    ->with(array('data'=>true,'uid'=>100));

})
);

Route::get('/something2',array('as'=>'firstpass',function()
{
  if(Session::get("data")==true) 
  { 
    $uid=Session::get('uid'); 
    return App::make('HomeController')->somePage($uid); 
  }
  else return  Redirect::to('/');
}
));
```

controller:

```
public function somePage()
{
    $params=array(
    'title'=>trans('welcome.welcome'), 
    'lang'=>$lang=Config::get('app.locale')

    );
     $view = View::make('firstpass',$params)->with(array('data'=>true,'uid'=>10));

    return $view;// 
    Response::view('firstpass',$params);//->with(array('data'=>true,'uid'=>10));
}
```

I have no idea why after simple reload route can't get: Session::get('data')==true and redirects me to /.

But if in controller I write
die(print_r(Session:all()));
I always ( even after refresh get ):

```
Array
(
[_token] => 6n6qb2vTxuunraTKVXvfrBsJ1mCddOZkgwb
[flash] => Array
    (
        [old] => Array
            (
                [0] => data
                [1] => uid
            )

        [new] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[data] => 1
[uid] => 100
)
```

I think reason is inside return value, I tried Response::make, Response::view, return View::, but nothing of this work, what I do wrong?

Maybe problem in that session store data by native driver in /app/storage/session

it's creates file but data  empty in every request
_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"XCJlvuFO2RCpKZYiW0Amm23DP5jwsmcC1Uq9vIS7B";s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"new";a:0:{}s:3:"old";a:0:{}}}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1387124689;s:1:"c";i:1387123303;s:1:"l";s:4:"7200";}

even if I add in view
    {{Session::put('data',true)}}
    {{Session::put('uid',10)}}
after print_r(Session::all())

```
Array
(
[_token] => EbF7RexCI97QM3jFUilWZsNIMiqyhdAcRcXUY8kB
[flash] => Array
    (
        [new] => Array
            (
            )

        [old] => Array
            (
                [0] => data
                [1] => uid
            )

    )

[data] => 1
[uid] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` method **flashes** data to the session; this means that the data will only be available to the first request, so this is the expected behavior.